# Problem purging keyvault with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

This is the task I created on Azure

```
# Pipeline that purges the deleted KeyVault. pr: none trigger: none

pool:   vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'   name: MyPool

variables:
- group: devopsforai-aml-vg

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2   inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Remove-AzKeyVault -VaultName "msftMLOPs-AML-KV" -ResourceGroupName "mlops-RG" -PassThru'
```

I have a hosted agent and when I run my pipeline I get the error on the image below:
[image]

```
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

Comment: Please have a try with the ```-Force ``` parameter  and ```-Confirm:$false```

Comment: Thanks. Changed the script to:  script: 'Remove-AzKeyVault -VaultName "msftMLOPs-AML-KV" -ResourceGroupName "mlops-RG" -Force -Confirm:$false' to add the arguments but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is finally the step I used to purge the KeyVault:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'azure-resource-connection'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: 'Remove-AzKeyVault -VaultName "msftMLOPs-AML-KV" -InRemovedState -Force -Location "Canada Central"'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```